# Combining pandas dataframes in this way

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe `df1` :-

| REGION | DATE | Count | TIME PER ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2021-03-22 | 2 | 44 |

I have another dataframe `df2` :-

| ID | REGION | DATE | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | ABC | 2021-03-22 | 198 |
| 75 | ABC | 2021-03-22 | 250 |

I want to achieve this :-

| ID | REGION | DATE | TIME | TIME PER ID | TOTAL TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | ABC | 2021-03-22 | 198 | 44 | 242 |
| 75 | ABC | 2021-03-22 | 250 | 44 | 294 |

Essentially I want to match the `REGION` and `DATE` and whatever value for `TIME PER ID` from `df1` I want to populate that for those rows in `df2` which matches the region and Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge both dataframes and then create the new column.

```
output_df = df2.merge(df1, on=['REGION', 'DATE'], how='left')
output_df.loc[:, 'TOTAL'] = output_df['Time'] + output_df['TIME PER ID']
```

Comment: Thx.Ill try this. To select only specific columns from `df2`  while I do this merge I can give it in `df2['col1','col2']`?

Comment: Yes, you can do `df2[['col1', 'col2']]`, remember you need two square brackets when you want to select more than one column.